# What is a good regular expression to match a URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have an input box which will detect the URL and parse the data.

So right now, I am using:

```
var urlR = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)
           (?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
var url= content.match(urlR);
```

The problem is, when I enter a URL like `www.google.com`, its not working. when I entered `http://www.google.com`, it is working.

I am not very fluent in regular expressions. Can anyone help me?

Comment: John Gruber's [Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) is also good. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927719/url-regex-does-not-work-in-javascript) for how to modify it to work in Javascript.

Comment: "/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/"

Comment: This is marked for duplicate but this question is asking for js and the other question is not asking for a js solution

Comment: See https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: `(www|http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]`

Comment: Here is NPM plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex

Comment: This should do it https://regex101.com/r/S2CbwM/1

Comment: @jose920405 I love your your extended regexp because it's simple. I've just tested it, it needed a little adjustment to forbid the `"` in the URL, i.e. : `(www|http:|https:)+[^\s"]+[\w]`

Comment: I've made a little adjustment to the regex by @MukulJain to validate for a full URL with a TLD before returning true, as the other expression validated partial URLs: `^(https?:\/\/)\S*\.(\S){2,}`

Comment: url doesn't start from `www`...

Comment: or you can refer this regex tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiqXWDyywog

Comment: `/(?:(?:https?)://)(?:localhost|(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))\\.?)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$/i` <-can be used with re2, this lib https://github.com/neosiae/is-valid-http-url

Comment: You're mixing protocols (https) and domain names (www). Besides, you're not allow ftp protocol for instance. Endly, there are many cases not allowed (http authentication, not default port, etc). Here is a more generic proposal: https://regex101.com/r/gCXX9j/1 
It allows subparts extraction and includes internal domain names. 
^(?:(http?|s?ftp):\/\/|file:\/\/\/)?(([\P{Cc}]+):([\P{Cc}]+)@)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*)(:[0-9]{1,5})?($|\/[\w\-\._~:\/?[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+(\#[\w]*)?$)

Answer (score 1053):

Regex if you want to ensure URL starts with HTTP/HTTPS:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

If you do not require HTTP protocol:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

To try this out see http://regexr.com?37i6s, or for a version which is less restrictive http://regexr.com/3e6m0.

Example JavaScript implementation:

```js
const expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi;
const regex = new RegExp(expression);
const t = 'www.google.com';

if (t.match(regex)) {
  alert("Successful match");
} else {
  alert("No match");
}
```

Comment: For got to mention use this site http://gskinner.com/RegExr/  to test Regex and view common samples

Comment: var urlRegex = /(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?$/; Is it like this? not working either.

Comment: Look here http://regexr.com?2s81g     you can see in the sample text that matches the URL regex are highlighted in blue

Comment: how do i use in javascritp context? when i add this in website.. javascript not working anymore.. i think they are error

Comment: I have updated my orginal answer to show full JavaScript example of the regex.   I also changed the regex slightly

Comment: In your example the query string of http://RegExr.com?2rjl6 is not caught.

Comment: @dmnc yes it is. I copied and pasted the code into firebug and changed www.google.com to regexr.com?2rji6 and it alerted sucessful match

Comment: @Daveo. Now I look back at that gskinner.com/RegExr link I used to test (you can see the results here http://regexr.com?2s715), it's built in Flash. Maybe it isn't using the javascript regex engine at all...

Comment: ok this one will match `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?`

Comment: This still matches URLs without a valid TLD, ie: "http://foo/file.html"

Comment: regex.test('//.com') => true

Comment: Don't forget about port numbers: "http://example.com:80/test"
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}(\:[0-9]+)?\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi

Comment: This didn't work with query params, e.g.
http://www.booking.com/hotel/id/champlung-sari-ubud.en-gb.html?aid=356992;label=gog235jc-hotel-en-id-okawati-nobrand-ch-com;sid=32c5d07ac3a021d4c4fd640290313345;dcid=1

Comment: Doesn't work for url with non-English characters: `"http://正妹.香港/‎" false`

Comment: this does not match URL containing ``,`` such as ``http://res.cloudinary.com/hrscywv4p/image/upload/c_fill,g_faces:center,h_128,w_128/yflwk7vffgwyyenftkr7.png``. Minor edit to fix that ``[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=,]*)``

Comment: `http://www.c:ool.com.au` shouldn't be a valid url, there must be at most one `:` after the `//` and it should be followed by digits and then a `/` or `?` or the end of the URL

Comment: this also match http(s)?://www.blablabla.something
((https?:\/\/)|(www\.)|(https?:\/\/www\.))([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{2,256})\.([a-z]{2,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)

Comment: question - why the double slash inside the last character class?

in this portion of the regex

[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]

there is a double slash, which doesn't seem necessary to me? You are placing twice the same character within the character class, and if you intended to escape the normal slash, this will be futile since escaping is performed with backslash?...

Comment: Here is the refined version of @Daveo's Regex that worked the best for me: https://regex101.com/r/hU9aV3/2

Comment: This is not working for 'http://localhost:60001/#/tab/dash'.
 /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi.test('http://localhost:60001/#/tab/dash');
false

Comment: This is wrong.
gtlds can be longer than 6 char and comprise non ascii characters.

Comment: This doesn't match twitter links that are just t.co   Need to change the {2,256} to {1,256}

Comment: this returns invalid `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_(film_series)`

Comment: If you want the Regex to recognise Capital or Mixed case letters, you should change .[a-z]{2,4} to .[a-zA-Z]{2,4}

You might also want to consider changing matching number range from {2,4} as domain names these days are getting longer and longer (e.g. .consulting, .marketing, .shopping etc)

Comment: doesn't work if url has spaces.
t = 'www.google.com withspace'
t.match(regex) // returns true

Comment: This did not found my website: `http://www.نبی.com/` :-D

Comment: This doesn't work for `http://12.23.12.23:8080/example` though it is valid

Comment: Matches `...and`

Comment: This does not detect `localhost` as a URL.

Comment: If you're using python, be sure to use raw strings or escape the "\b", or else this won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3995034/3412775.

Comment: It considers this invalid url `www.baidu.com:443.us/path/to/the/file` as valid

Comment: @AminJafari this should match your example: `https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=()]*)`

Comment: Remove the two chars '\/' after the '\b(' to fix the bug of not matching ?queries=hi. Also, adjust '{2,4}' to be '{1,4}' since there are some single letter domains.

Comment: I'm confused about `//` in the last group. Should it be `\/`?

Comment: It should not be used in production. It also says `true` for `\\\\\\||||@@@@https://www.google.com`

Comment: good answer but you missed the star character \\* so the full valid string is: https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=\\*]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=\\*]*) have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Comment: this does work with `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: How can this be a valid URL `http://google.com......` ?

Comment: @Daveo Also, How can this be a valid URL `https://www.google_.com`?

Comment: This regex will match all url with more than one dots, like ```www...google...com```, you need to check for the \. to be equal to only one. Try this regex as it's working better with the dots. ```^https?:\/\/(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#=]{2,256}(\.){1})+[a-z]{2,6}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._?&\/+~#=]{2,256}|:[0-9]{2,})*```. someone know how to change this and avoid ```www.aa```  ??

Comment: I don't expect this regex to handle all extreme cases like pointed out above but here is a simple use case that I use all the time in real life `http://192.168.1.19` or `http://192.168.1.19:5000` that should be valid but fails.

Comment: @JustinA updated to work  - see here https://regexr.com/3e6m0

Comment: Diego Perini made a very good regex that covers almost all possible cases, you might want to check it out here:
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: https://themadhurgupta.blogspot.com/2019/09/regular-expression.html

Comment: doesnt work for new urls like https://mysite.restaurant  because of 6 letter ending limit. It should be 18 i think, because of e.,g. `.northwesternmutual`. Got the list from `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains`

Comment: but this matches *msa...com*

Comment: Doesn't work for utf8 characters http://食狮.com.cn

Comment: `http://.google.com` is also matched with this one!! is that ok?

Comment: Also matches on `http://www.google..com`

Comment: Don't cover this type of urls: https://www.chartmill.com/analyze.php?utm_source=stocktwits&amp;utm_medium=FA&amp;utm_content=HEALTH&amp;utm_campaign=social_tracking#/FSLR?r=fa&amp;key=b431cf47-ec7e-4226-b864-511b6081b3be

Comment: The first regexp is invalid !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: this matches the emails as well

Comment: By your regex, `http://example.com:806666` is valid

Comment: It doesn't match "http://www.example.com/hello/world.do?key=python", which is a valid url.

Comment: It doesn't match URL with special characters : é à ï ...

Comment: It misses some special characters like asterisk (*). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644092

Comment: Please note that it matches prefixed and suffixed URLs, e.g. **prefix**https://example.com**suffix**. To avoid that, the expression should begin with `^` and end with `$`: `^https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)$`.

Comment: 31.12.2023 - is not valid url :D

Comment: does not work for https://blabla.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/bla-project-delivery/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B167E7E9A-F55E-4385-BA20-FCD2BBF2BCC6%7D&amp;file=TPGT-bla%20-%20Production%20MPN%20HLD%20Rev%200.52.docx&amp;action=default&amp;mobileredirect=true

Comment: It is better to have a regex that match url in all these conditions:
1- with or without protocol
2- with or without subdomain
3- with or without path
4- with or without query params

I suggest this regex:
^(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)$

Answer (score 409):

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})
```

Will match the following cases

- `http://www.foufos.gr`
- `https://www.foufos.gr`
- `http://foufos.gr`
- `http://www.foufos.gr/kino`
- `http://werer.gr`
- `www.foufos.gr`
- `www.mp3.com`
- `www.t.co`
- `http://t.co`
- `http://www.t.co`
- `https://www.t.co`
- `www.aa.com`
- `http://aa.com`
- `http://www.aa.com`
- `https://www.aa.com`
- `badurlnotvalid://www.google.com - captured url www.google.com`
- `htpp://www.google.com - captured url www.google.com`

Will NOT match the following

- `www.foufos`
- `www.foufos-.gr`
- `www.-foufos.gr`
- `foufos.gr`
- `http://www.foufos`
- `http://foufos`
- `www.mp3#.com`

```js
var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);

var check = [
  'http://www.foufos.gr',
  'https://www.foufos.gr',
  'http://foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos.gr/kino',
  'http://werer.gr',
  'www.foufos.gr',
  'www.mp3.com',
  'www.t.co',
  'http://t.co',
  'http://www.t.co',
  'https://www.t.co',
  'www.aa.com',
  'http://aa.com',
  'http://www.aa.com',
  'https://www.aa.com',
  'badurlnotvalid://www.google.com',
  'htpp://www.google.com',
  'www.foufos',
  'www.foufos-.gr',
  'www.-foufos.gr',
  'foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos',
  'http://foufos',
  'www.mp3#.com'
];

check.forEach(function(entry) {
  let match = entry.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    $("#output").append( "<div style='float:left'>Success: " + entry + "</div><div style='float:right'>Captured url: " + match + "</div><br>" );
  } else {
    $("#output").append( "<div style='float:left'>Fail: " + entry + "</div><br>" );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

[Check it in rubular - latest version](https://rubular.com/r/Xi0Dr4xJzosdu0)

[<del>Check it in rubular - old version</del>](https://rubular.com/r/eGPe4bGlwMd98E)

[<del>Check it in rubular - old version</del>](https://www.rubular.com/r/WacnNAOQZa)

Comment: I changed your expression a bit so it will work in all cases i need, including uri with http:// or http://www "/([^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi"

Comment: Sorry, in the comment h-t-t-p-:-/-/ was sanitized!

Comment: This regex is no longer valid as new custom gTLDs can have URLs like https://calendar.google/

Comment: what if we have to remove web page and make it only for websites . I mean if we remove `http://www.foufos.gr/kino` from matched cases. what would be the change in regex ?

Comment: @ajeetlakhani you can just add the / to the last group of not allowed characters `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s\/]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s\/]{2,})`

Comment: but it will match `http://www.foufos`  and will not match `regex.com`

Comment: Who cares about the special www subdomain anymore? Nobody!

Comment: Another problem with this regular expression is `?!`, negative look-aheads are not supported by some libraries, particularly Go regex library because then O(n) time complexity is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: it is giving true for `www.mp3#.com` which is I think wrong

Comment: @mrugesh-tank I have edited the regex

Comment: This will unfortunately also catch "www.example.com.", which I think ending with a "." is also invalid.

Comment: @ruben-martinez-jr you could add ".," or any other punctuation you like in the [^\s] part but you would miss a url like "www.example.com/test.html"

Comment: Does it match subdomains? Like `http://docs.google.com`?

Comment: @augustin-riedinger It will match if the http or https is prepended so `http://docs.google.com` will match but `docs.google.com` will not match

Comment: Hi and thanks for this regex! Question: I tried to add the possibility, to use intranet links such as e.g. `http://intranet/index.html` and also `mailto` e.g. `mailto:sample@sample.com`.

Tried out this regex: `/^((http(s)?)|(ftp(s)?):\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm` but it did not work for the two examples below. What's wrong?

Comment: @webta.st.ic You could add `|https?:\/\/[^\s]+|mailto:[^\s]+` just before the closing bracket and capture these two cases. What it does is that it states if you have a string starting with `http://` or `https://` or `mailto:` then capture it. This also captures the two cases not captured by the original expression (`http://www.foufos`, `http://foufos`)

Comment: Hi @foufos I made working a RegEx for my required cases: `/^(((http(s)?|(ftp(s)?)):\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})+(\:[0-9]{5})?|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm;` Here also the regex test: https://regex101.com/r/XFvQjr/4 Thanks!

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `https://wwwsomething.com`

Comment: @undefined the regex is designed to match urls either starting with `www.` (dot included) or not starting with `www` therefore I am not changing the regex, but in order to achieve it you could change the `www\.` parts of the regex to `www\.?`

Comment: better than the above one for sure

Comment: This matches on `www.google..com`

Comment: @erion-s it is a trade-off since you might want to capture `www.google.com/test.html`

Comment: @foufos how come that's a trade-off? Surely it is possible to write an expression that accepts `www.google.com/test.html` but does not accept `www.google..com`?

Comment: This matches " characters, such as `http://www.google.com/"asdf"`.  I believe " is not a legal URL character

Comment: Note: This answer supports `https://localhost`, not found in the accepted answer

Comment: This regex validates "htps://www.google.com " when it shouldn't

Comment: @user2410203 it matches the `www.google.com` part of the string so I am not sure that it makes it wrong. You could add a whitespace character match in front of the `www` (`|\swww`) so that it will expect a space before the www

Comment: This is also matching https://www.aa.com" (Note the double quote in the end). The url should match but double quotes not be part of the match

Comment: upgrade this regex:

`/^(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|(?!www\.))(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.)+(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,})\/?$/i`

link to test:
https://rubular.com/r/L5svOYSnxfweQp

Comment: This is great, it even works with Google Maps links. But is it possible to ignore tailing characters? If for example I have a link in between parenthesis `(https://google.com)` it's matching `https://google.com)` which is not valid for me.

Comment: This also matches invalid links such as htpp://www.google.com.

Comment: @BrightIntelDusk it actually mathces the www.google.com and not the htpp://

Comment: @foufos : Actually, I tested it and it matches on `Success: htpp://www.google.com`. I had unit tests running in NodeJS that caught this one. In addition, I ran it in a Chrome Snippet and verified that this regexp matches on htpp://www.google.com. Test your assumptions.

Comment: Here's the codepen to prove that this RegExp matches on htpp://www.google.com  https://codepen.io/QLuminary/pen/qBMLJzj

Comment: It even matches the entire URL for `badurlnotvalid://www.google.com`.

Comment: @BrightIntelDusk I am sorry for the confusion, I just updated the code snippet to show the captured match. In your cases the actual url was captured, ignoring the invalid htpp part

Comment: g.cn still valid, but not for your regexp

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. [https://example.com./](https://example.com./) is a perfectly valid URL, using a fully-qualified domain name. (Nowadays, most systems don't really resolve partially-qualified domain names, so unqualified domain names are almost the same thing as fully-qualified ones.)

Answer (score 67):

These are the droids you're looking for.  This is taken from [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) which is the library you should really use to do this.  But if you want to roll your own, who am I to stop you?  If you want pure regex then you can just take out the length check.  I think it's a good idea to test the length of the URL though if you really want to determine compliance with the spec.

```
 function isURL(str) {
     var urlRegex = '^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?$';
     var url = new RegExp(urlRegex, 'i');
     return str.length < 2083 && url.test(str);
}
```

**Test:**

```
function isURL(str) {
         var urlRegex = '^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?$';
         var url = new RegExp(urlRegex, 'i');
         return str.length < 2083 && url.test(str);
    }
var check = [
  'http://www.foufos.gr',
  'https://www.foufos.gr',
  'http://foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos.gr/kino',
  'http://werer.gr',
  'www.foufos.gr',
  'www.mp3.com',
  'www.t.co',
  'http://t.co',
  'http://www.t.co',
  'https://www.t.co',
  'www.aa.com',
  'http://aa.com',
  'http://www.aa.com',
  'https://www.aa.com',
  'www.foufos',
  'www.foufos-.gr',
  'www.-foufos.gr',
  'foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos',
  'http://foufos',
  'www.mp3#.com'
];

for (let index = 0; index < check.length; index++) {
var url=check[index]
  if  (isURL(check[index]))
    console.log(`${url}         ✔`);
else{
  console.log(`${url}          ❌`);
}
  
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning **this can crash your browser**. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrnambtt/9/

Comment: Just a bit more info on the comment by @RubenMartinezJr. - it *does* max out the CPU on Chrome and Firefox (Mac OS), but interestingly *does not* max out the CPU on Safari.

Comment: Great! But the function is returning false for a Wikipedia URL: `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Lagrange_equation`

Answer (score 48):

Another possible solution, above solution failed for me in parsing query string params.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

if(regex.test("http://google.com")){
  alert("Successful match");
}else{
  alert("No match");
}
```

In this solution please feel free to modify `[-0-9A-Za-z\.@:%_\+~#=`, to match the domain/sub domain name. In this solution query string parameters are also taken care.

If you are not using `RegEx`, then from the expression replace `\\` by `\`.

Hope this helps.

**Test:-**

```
function IsUrl(url){
    var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

if(regex.test(url)){
  console.log(`${url}         ✔`);
}else{
  console.log(`${url}          ❌`);
}}
var check = [
  'http://www.foufos.gr',
  'https://www.foufos.gr',
  'http://foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos.gr/kino',
  'http://werer.gr',
  'www.foufos.gr',
  'www.mp3.com',
  'www.t.co',
  'http://t.co',
  'http://www.t.co',
  'https://www.t.co',
  'www.aa.com',
  'http://aa.com',
  'http://www.aa.com',
  'https://www.aa.com',
  'www.foufos',
  'www.foufos-.gr',
  'www.-foufos.gr',
  'foufos.gr',
  'http://www.foufos',
  'http://foufos',
  'www.mp3#.com'
];
for (let index = 0; index < check.length; index++) {
    IsUrl(check[index])
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: `var regex = /^(http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?|ftp:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(\/(.)*)?(\?(.)*)?/g;` works for me

Comment: nice solution but fails for http://foo.co.uk... must be set to this var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|(www\\.)?){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?"); Thanks Amar.

Comment: Fails for something like: `https://www.elh` or `http://www.elh`. Although @Tony solution passed this case, it fails with `www.elh`

Comment: If I test
`Hi there, https://www.atrable.com/#motivation is the motivation of making my app`
, this Regex includes `is the motivation of making my app` as a part of url too.

To fix this, I modified it a little bit: `(http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?|ftp:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/[^\s]*)?(\?[^\s]*)?`

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to put together some JavaScript to validate a domain name (ex. google.com) and if it validates enable a submit button. I thought that I would share my code for those who are looking to accomplish something similar. It expects a domain without any http:// or www. value. The script uses a stripped down regular expression from above for domain matching, which isn't strict about fake TLD.

http://jsfiddle.net/nMVDS/1/

```
$(function () {
  $('#whitelist_add').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
        //If there is no text within the input, disable the button
        $('.whitelistCheck').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        // Domain name regular expression
        var regex = new RegExp("^([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");
        if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
            // Domain looks OK
            //alert("Successful match");
            $('.whitelistCheck').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            // Domain is NOT OK
            //alert("No match");
            $('.whitelistCheck').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="domain_management.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="whitelist_add" id="whitelist_add" placeholder="domain.com">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success whitelistCheck" disabled='disabled'>Add to Whitelist</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Another choice for subdomains:  `https?:\/\/[\w+-_]+.{1}[\wñÑ+-_]+.{1}[\w+]{2,10}`